# Calling functions from other files "Can't find symbol"

Tags: java, function, class, methods

Trying to call some functions from various classes for an exercise.

We are told to use the following function calls,

```
MonthName.month_name();
WeekdayName.weekday_name();
MonthOffset.month_offset();
WeekdayCalculator.is_leap();
```

When I tried MonthName.month_name(); It says it is a non static method,  it is infact a static method as seen in below, I sorted that by calling it like,

```
MonthName monthObject = new MonthName();
```

Which sorted that problem out.  But every other function I try to call i get the msg it can't find symbol.

The class I am trying to call the functions in

```
public class callingfunctionsfromotherfiles



public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // TODO code application logic here

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String finalDate="";
    System.out.println("Pleaase enter your date of birth in this format dd mm yyyy");
    String dob=scan.nextLine(); // date of birth entered by the user


    String d = dob.substring(0,2); //split the dob into 3 parts
    String m = dob.substring(3, 5);
    String y = dob.substring(6, 10);

    int day = Integer.parseInt(d); //convert dob strings to int
    int month = Integer.parseInt(m);
    int year = Integer.parseInt(y);
    MonthName monthObject = new MonthName();
 // MonthName.month_name(month); non static???

 System.out.println(finalDate= "You where born on " + week_day(day, month, year) +", " + monthObject.month_name(month) + ", "+ day + ", " + year );

}



public static String week_day(int day, int month, int year)  // returns a string value for the week day with integer parameters of day,month,year
   {

       MonthOffset offsetObject = new MonthOffset(); //"Can't find symbol"
       WeekDayCalculator leapObject = new WeekDayCalculator(); //"Can't find symbol"
       WeekDayName wkdayObject = new WeekDayName(); //"Can't find symbol"

   int yy = year - 1900;
   int total = yy / 4 + yy + day + offsetObject.month_offset(month);
  // weekDayCalculator.month_offset();

   //WeekDayCalculator.is_leap();
    boolean leap = leapObject.is_leap(year); //pass "year" into the is_leap method which returns true or false
    if(leap == true && month == 1 || month == 2) //if it is a leap year and the month == 1(january) 2(february) subtract 1 from the total
    {
        total-= -1;
    }


   total = total %7; //total is remainder of (total / 7)
   String finalDay = wkdayObject.weekday_name(total); // call weekday_name and pass in total, giving finalDay a string value from weekday_name

    return finalDay;




}
```

This is the class & function that works when I create an object,  but also tells me the function is non static when really it is.

```
public class monthname
{
public static String month_name(int num)

{
    String month ="";

    if( num == 1)
    {
        month ="January";
    }

    else if(num == 2)
    {
        month ="Feburary";
    }

    else if(num == 3)
    {
        month ="March";
    }

    else if(num == 4)
    {
        month ="April";
    }

    else if(num == 5)
    {
        month ="May";
    }

    else if(num == 6)
    {
        month ="June";
    }

    else if(num == 7)
    {
        month ="July";
    }

    else if(num == 8)
    {
        month ="August";
    }

    else if(num == 9)
    {
        month ="September";
    }

    else if(num == 10)
    {
        month ="October";
    }

    else if(num == 11)
    {
        month ="November";
    }

    else if(num == 12)
    {
        month ="December";
    }

    else
    {
        month ="error";
    }
    return month;

}
}
```

And this is one of the classes & functions where it can't find symbol.  Will post more if needed.

```
public class monthoffset
{
 public static int month_offset(int month)
{
    int offset =0;

    if (month == 1)
    {
        offset=1;
    }
    else if (month == 2)
    {
        offset = 4;
    }
    else if (month == 3)
    {
        offset = 4;
    }
    else if (month == 4)
    {
        offset = 0;
    }
    else if (month == 5)
    {
        offset = 2;
    }
    else if (month == 6)
    {
        offset = 5;
    }
    else if (month == 7)
    {
        offset = 0;
    }
    else if (month == 8)
    {
        offset = 3;
    }
    else if (month == 9)
    {
        offset = 6;
    }
    else if (month == 10)
    {
        offset = 1;
    }
    else if (month == 11)
    {
        offset = 4;
    }
    else if(month ==12)
    {
        offset=6;
    }

    else
    {
       offset = -1;
    }


    return offset;
}
```

}

Comment: I only see one method name `month_name` in the code you posted. And it is in the class `monthoffset` and requires an int parameter. So obviously `MonthName.month_name()` will not work.

Comment: Also please note that Java is case sensitive. `monthoffset` and `MonthOffset` are not the same thing.

Comment: Ok...when pasting in my code i pasted monthoffset instead of monthname as the class,  not like that on my ide.  I deleted everythig and started again,   still the exact same problem. The class names are now coppied exactly as they are.

Answer (score 1):

MonthOffset is not monthoffset. You have syntax erros, Try to use Eclipse or IntelliJ to have some help from an IDE.

Comment: Ok but then Why does MonthName(); work when the class is monthname?

Answer (score 1):

It's syntax error. You don't have class MonthOffset etc. Change name of your class from monthoffset to Monthoffset.

Convention is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: But i can call the month_name() function from the monthname class using MonthName monthObject = new MonthName();

Comment: Maybe you have other classes with correct name. IMO In mentioned code it is not possible.